# HA, Lurie, Characterization of suspension

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

In [HA, p24](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf) Lurie wrote

> The suspension functor $\Sigma_{C} :C \rightarrow C $  is essentially characterized by the existence of a natural homotopy equivalence
>   $$ Map_C(\Sigma X,Y) \rightarrow  \Omega Map_C(X,Y) $$

I am confused. How is this deduced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object $\Sigma X$ is defined as the pushout (in the $\infty$-categorical sense) of $0\leftarrow X\to 0$. By definition, this means that $Map_C(\Sigma X,Y)$ is the pullback of spaces (in the $\infty$-categorical sense) $Map_C(0,Y)\times_{Map_C(X,Y)}Map_C(0,Y)\equiv 0\times_{Map_C(X,Y)}0$, where $0$ is denoting the zero object both in $C$ and in pointed spaces. The latter pullback is $\Omega Map_C(X,Y)$, by definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin. I agree with everything you said. After your first line, you said, "by definition". But by my definition $\Sigma X$ is the cone point of the pushout. It is not clear to me why it is the homotopy pullback of these spaces from the quasicategory definition. I suppose Lurie proves this somewhere?

Comment: @BryanShih I’m not sure how we’re saying anything different-the cone point of the pushout  versus the pushout.

Comment: Sorry , I am still lost. By my definition, we have a diagram $p:\Lambda^2_0 \rightarrow C$, and $\Sigma X$, is the cone $p'(\infty)$ of a final object $p' \in C_{p/}$.  How does it follow that $Map_C(p'(\infty), y)$ is the homotopy limit of the spaces you mentioned?

Comment: @BryanShih It is a very fundamental fact that $Map_C(\mathrm{colim} p,y)\simeq \lim Map_C(p(-),y)$. Lurie doesn't always emphasize what a categorist would emphasize, but see Section 4.3 of *Elements of $\infty$-Category Theory* by Riehl and Verity. The meta-point here is that the whole reason people are excited about $\infty$-category theory is that basic facts about categories are also true for $\infty$-categories, and you can't get much more fundamental than homs out of a colimit being the limit of the homs.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your patience. Then I suppose work still has to be done to show this in the quasicategory model?

Comment: @BryanShih I’m not sure exactly what you mean by that. It’s a theorem in any model. One does have to show that quasicategories satisfy Riehl and Verity’s axioms. But don’t get too bogged down in all these details right off the bat.

Comment: Ah, yes, I meant supposing I do not know RV's work, and only following Lurie's... which I do not see the pros if it is all done in generality in RV?

Comment: @BryanShih I’ve said before that I don’t think it makes sense to try to learn $\infty$-category theory from Lurie alone if you don’t have a deep background in abstract homotopy theory, whereas R-V may be more plausible. Yes, it would take a fair bit of work to prove this result just in Lurie’s context.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes, I also started to look at Cisinki's and Rezk's notes. But returning to Lurie's time to time. RV's work seem interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If $[]$ denotes descending to the homotopy category, the equivalence implies $[\operatorname{Map} (\Sigma X, -)]$ is naturally isomorphic to $[\Omega \operatorname{Map}(X,-)]$. If we had another functor $F$ with the same property as in the question, then it would also be the case $[\operatorname{Map} (FX, -)]$ is naturally isomorphic to $[\Omega \operatorname{Map}(X,-)]$. Basic category theory says that two representing objects are isomorphic. The naturality of the homotopy equivalence implies that the isomorphisms can be chosen to assemble into a natural isomorphism $\Sigma \rightarrow F$.

If you are in a suitable category like compactly generated spaces, then this can also be deduced from the adjointness of smash and mapping space.

Comment: I am in fact concerned precisely by the first statement you wrote: $[Map(\Sigma X,-)]$ is naturually isomorphic to $[\Omega Map(X,-)]$ how do you prove this rigorously?

Comment: You should look at the explicit isomorphism guaranteed by Yoneda lemma.

Comment: Does thet yoneda even exist in this context? I agree with what you wrote after line one. Its just the first line is not clear.

Comment: These are functors into set so yes. Yoneda gives you a single isomorphism. You must use naturality of the homotopy equivalence to argue that together the isomorphisms give you a natural isomorphism between functors.

Comment: Sorry, this is still unclear to me. The suspension here is defined for that of $\infty$-category $C$. Whilst the $\Omega$ here is on the mapping spaces.

Comment: My omega should be an sigma. I’ll edit it.