# (co)Limits in $\infty$-categories.

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, enriched-category-theory

It seems to me that the following must be true, and has been used in [Lurie's HA](http://www.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf), and in my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412966/ha-lurie-characterization-of-suspension). The precise statement is:

> Let $p:K \rightarrow C$ be a small diagram in $C$. Here $C$ is an $\infty$-category ,$K$ an arbitrary simplicial set.  We follow [HTT, 1.2.13.5](http://www.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HTT.pdf), to say that $p(\infty)$ is the cone point of limit $\bar{p}$.
>
> **Claim:** In $hC$, $p(\infty)$ is a $H$ -enriched limit of $hp:hK \rightarrow hC$. $H$ denotes the homotopy category of spaces.

I could not spell this out this rigorously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is that a limit in an infinity category indices an $H$-enriched limit in the homotopy category, right? In that case, this is very far from true. It would imply the same claim about ordinary limits, since an isomorphism in $H$ induces an isomorphism of sets after applying $\pi_0$. And then counterexamples are everywhere.

Generally $hC$ doesn’t have (co)limits are all, and they certainly don’t agree with the (co)limits in $C$. Pushouts are a good place to start for intuition. If $C$ is the $\infty$-category of spaces then $S^2$ is the pushout of two points along the map $S^1\to *$. But in the homotopy category, the same pushout does exist-it’s just a point.

Comment: Ah, you are right... Do you mind explaining  my other question? (which I linked)

Comment: I think my fundamental confusion is what does a limit in $C$ tell us about the cone in the corresponding homotopy category?

Comment: @BryanShih it tells us essentially nothing. Very few limits in the $\infty$-category even induce *weak* limits in the homotopy category. It is better to get an idea for what a limit in an $\infty$-category means by looking in the simplicial world, I think, where they can be constructed as certain weighted limits, see Riehl's Categorical Homotopy Theory.